# Why does timezone info from Ruby sequel and Postgres psql differ?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, timezone

Here is a query result from Postgres:

```
$ psql ... -c 'select the_date from foo where foo_id in (998,999)'
     the_date      
------------------------
 2012-03-07 09:34:47.98
 2012-03-16 11:31:25.336
```

the_date is "timestamp without time zone".

Here is a Ruby program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sequel'

@DB = Sequel.connect({...})
query = "select the_date from foo where foo_id in (998,999)"
@DB[query].each do |row|
  warn row
end
```

and some output:

```
{:the_date=>2012-03-07 09:34:47 -0600}
{:the_date=>2012-03-16 11:31:25 -0500}
```

Where does the -0500 and -0600 come from?  That is the "[Olson timezone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)" of the server and the client machines (US/Central), but why does Ruby add it and psql does not?

I've been reading [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES), and I'm thoroughly confused.

The server is Postgres 9.0.4, the client is psql 9.1.4, sequel is 3.33.0.

Comment: You may find the information at this [closely related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9571392/939860) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column is of type 'timestamp without timezone'. Thus when Postgres displays a value in this column it just displays the timestamp with no timezone. However, Sequel wants to convert a Postgres timestamp to an instance of the Ruby Time class, and an instance of the Time class must have a timezone specified - either it's a time in the local timezone or it's a time in UTC. Thus Sequel must choose one. By default, it's choosing your local timezone.

You may configure the database and application timezone in Sequel. See https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sequel/4.36.0/Sequel/Timezones

For example, here's the default Sequel behavior with a database I had handy:

```
>   c['select * from actors'].each do |row|; puts row[:created_at]; end
Thu Jul 12 20:33:17 -0400 2012
```

Here the timestamp is assumed to be in my local timezone (EDT).

However, if I do this:

```
> Sequel.database_timezone = :utc
 => :utc 
> c['select * from actors'].each do |row|; puts row[:created_at]; end
Thu Jul 12 20:33:17 UTC 2012
```

Then the timestamp is assumed to be in UTC.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  So Sequel's "local timestamp" behavior is sophisticated enough to take into account daylight savings time based on the timestamp itself (hence the -0500 and -0600)?

Comment: Yes --  although that sophistication is actually from Ruby's Time class. For example, for me in the Eastern zone, Time.parse('2012-03-07 09:34:47').to_s gives "Wed Mar 07 09:34:47 -0500 2012", while Time.parse('2012-03-16 11:31:25').to_s gives "Fri Mar 16 11:31:25 -0400 2012".

Answer (score 0):

I've had some strange dealings with ruby and dates/times/timestamps. It looks like the program is trying to convert the result into a known datatype and automatically casting it, which is why you receive the 5digit timezone code at the end.